# How to find the third largest integer in C without using arrays?

Tags: c, math

I need help, my program isn't working out, it keeps showing me 0 as the value! What is wrong with my code?

the program requires the user to enter the number of integers at the start.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{   
    int num;
    int largest= 0;
    int secondlargest= 0;
    int thirdlargest=0;
    printf("Please enter the number of integers:");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if(num > 2)
    {
        scanf("%d",&largest);

        while(--num > 0)
        {   
            int tmp;
            scanf("%d",&tmp);
            if(tmp>largest)
            largest=tmp;

            if(tmp > secondlargest && tmp < largest)
            secondlargest=tmp;

            if(tmp > thirdlargest && tmp < secondlargest && tmp < largest)
            thirdlargest=tmp;
        }
            printf("The third largest number is %d\n",thirdlargest);

    }
    else
    {
        printf("There is no third largest number.");
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

here is my code, as written above! I need to submit it without using array! Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: why the `C#` tag?

Comment: What should be printed in the event that 3 numbers are specified & 3 identical numbers are entered - should you print that value as third largest, print zero or do you want to print "There is no third largest number"?

Answer (score 2):

When you found the first or second largest, then you need to "shift" the smaller ones (and you can replace your second and 3rd if by 'else if'). 
If you want to handle negatives input set the 3 largest to the smallest int.  And use >= instead of > to handle duplicates.

```
    int num;
    int largest = INT_MIN;
    int secondlargest = INT_MIN;
    int thirdlargest = INT_MIN;
    printf("Please enter the number of integers:");
    scanf_s("%d", &num);

    if (num > 2)
    {
        scanf_s("%d", &largest);

        while (--num > 0)
        {
            int tmp;
            scanf_s("%d", &tmp);
            if (tmp >= largest){
                thirdlargest = secondlargest;
                secondlargest = largest;
                largest = tmp;
            } 
            else if (tmp >= secondlargest){
                thirdlargest = secondlargest;
                secondlargest = tmp;
            } 
            else if (tmp > thirdlargest)
                thirdlargest = tmp;
        }
        printf("The third largest number is %d\n", thirdlargest);

    }
    else
    {
        printf("There is no third largest number.");
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Indeed but considering the original code, I thought that won't be important. You just need to initialize the 1st, 2nd and 3rd largest to the smallest possible int

Comment: This code doesn't work if there is one or more duplicated numbers, e.g. the 3 numbers 1 3 3 returns 0 as the third largest.

Comment: Indeed.  I fixed it.  But as that was not the original question  not sure if we should cover all the cases instead of letting him find from himself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle negatives too, set your three largest values to the minimum integer.  Also use `else if` instead of `if` so you can use simple comparisons, instead of compound ones, followed by shifting your variables:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number;

    printf("Please enter the number of integers: ");
    (void) scanf("%d", &number);

    if (number < 3)
    {
        printf("There is no third largest number.");

        return 1;
    }

    int largest = INT_MIN;
    int secondlargest = INT_MIN;
    int thirdlargest = INT_MIN;

    while (number-- > 0)
    {
        int temporary;
        (void) scanf("%d", &temporary);

        if (temporary > largest)
        {
            thirdlargest = secondlargest;
            secondlargest = largest;
            largest = temporary;
        }
        else if (temporary > secondlargest)
        {
            thirdlargest = secondlargest;
            secondlargest = temporary;
        }
        else if (temporary > thirdlargest) {
            thirdlargest = temporary;
        }
    }

    printf("The third largest number is %d\n", thirdlargest);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudo code that simplifies and corrects your `if()` structure.

```
int largest1 = INT_MIN;
int largest2 = INT_MIN;
int largest3 = INT_MIN;

int input = ...;

if (input > largest3) {
  largest3 = input;
  if (largest3 > largest2) {
    swap(largest2, largest3);
    if (largest2 > largest1) {
      swap(largest1, largest2);
    }
  }
}
```